# Where to store JSON file inside Laravel folder structure

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to store some data in a JSON file. The data will be decoded using `json_decode` function and passed to view.

File example:

```
{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "name": "Aula Magna 1",
      "camera_url": "camera url",
      "audio_card": "audio card"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aula Magna 2",
      "camera_url": "camera url",
      "audio_card": "audio card"
    },
    {
       "name": "Aula Minor",
       "camera_url": "camera url",
       "audio_card": "audio card"
    }] 
}
```

I want to convert this file into an array so I can access it inside a view like so

```
@foreach( $rooms as $room)
   ....
@endforeach
```

Where inside Laravel folder structutre should be data file like this stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your file inside the `storage` folder as it is a non-public directory.

You can also place it in `resources` folder, but it is not the best place, as this folder is used for source files and is usually stored in source code repository (e.g. git).